# What is wrong with this Swift syntax?

Tags: swift

I can't figure out what is wrong with the following:

```
fileprivate func showInlineErrorMessage(_ message: String, forField textField: UITextField) {

        // Show error message
        errorLabel.text   = message
        errorLabel.isHidden = false

        // Highlight field on which the error is
        [usernameTextField, passwordTextField, birthYearTextField, genderTextField].forEach {
            updateHighlightOnTextField($0!, highlight: $0 === textField )
        }
    }
```

The specific part is `$0 === textField`

The compiler is showing the following error:

```
"?" must be followed by a call, member lookup, or a subscript
```

This is old code, so it seems something may have changed recently.

The called function is

```
fileprivate func updateHighlightOnTextField(_ textField: UITextField, highlight: Bool) {
        let highlightView = textField.superview!
        highlightView.layer.borderWidth = highlight ? 1.0 : 0.0
        highlightView.layer.borderColor = highlight ? DefaultTheme.lineColorError.cgColor : nil
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What is the signature of the `updateHighlightOnTextField` method? Why are you force-unwrapping `$0` as the first argument? Are one or more of the text fields optional? If the first argument is force-unwrapped, why isn't the second?

Comment: I just updated the question above with additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes swift cannot understand the type of an inline statement.
Have you tried:

**Creating an external Boolean:**

```
    [usernameTextField, passwordTextField, birthYearTextField, genderTextField].forEach {
        let isHighlighted: Bool = ($0 === textField)
        updateHighlightOnTextField($0!, highlight: isHighlighted)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the only approach I could get to work.

Answer (score 1):

The needless use of the force-unwrapping seems to be causing the problem.

If you change:

```
updateHighlightOnTextField($0!, highlight: $0 === textField)
```

to:

```
updateHighlightOnTextField($0, highlight: $0 === textField)
```

then the problem goes away.

This does assume that your text field properties are declared as either non-optional or as implicitly unwrapped optionals.

In the unlikely event that your text fields are declared as optionals then you can safely unwrap `$0` to avoid the use of `!`.

Comment: This makes no difference, wrapped or unwrapped the same problem occurs

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? My answer is based on actual tests in a Swift Playground. Eliminating the `!` does fix the problem.

Comment: Xcode version 8.3.3.  Xcode is also insisting that $0 is unwrapped with `!` because these are optionals